# Should my customer register Google reCaptcha, or should I do it for my customer?

Tags: recaptcha

An Customer ask me to implement it at his Webpage, because he don't have the technical Skills to do so.

I wonder, what's the right way to do this. 
On other Google-Services (like Google Search Console) the User can sign into his account and grant me permissions as Guest (he invite me as guest to his account and gave me permissions).

This is a clean way to do, because If I stop working for this customer, he can easily remove the permissions of my login and all is fine.

But how does it work at Google ReCaptcha?

Looking forward to hear, how you solve this.

Comment: Just do it for your customer. Most likely if your customer moves away, the other developer will do it for them again.

Answer (score 1):

it better to use the user's credentials for this purpose, just take client's primary or secondary email (or create a email for the project) and make it base for everything that's needed for your project like recatcha, search-console etc. you can use it as long as you are working, and client can simply change n give the credentials to next developer and he can continue.

i am web developer and i face this situation many times, this is best solution in my opinion.